# PHP: Parse .csv file with line breaks in field value (partly quoted)

Tags: php, csv, parsing, delimiter, multiline

There are some questions on this topic already however I did not find a satisfying answer yet. While common .csv reader software (e.g. Libre Office) can read the file without any problems PHP has problems with this.

Sample part of the file:

```
86010800,class,Table Games,,"(10005183, 10005184, 10005185)"
86011100,class,Toy Vehicles – Non-ride,,"(10005192, 10005190, 10005191, 10005193, 10005194, 10005195, 10005196)"
86011000,class,Toys – Ride-on,,"(10005187, 10005188, 10005441, 10005189)"
86010900,class,Toys/Games Variety Packs,,(10005186)
10001686,brick,Airbrushes (Powered),"Definition:
 Includes any products that can be described/observed as a powered 
machine that scatters paint using air pressure and which is used for 
design illustrations, fine art and delicate fine spray applications. The
 machine comprises of a compression or propulsion device to scatter the 
paint.Specifically excludes Spray Paint and Aerosols.Excludes Airbrushing Replacement Parts and Accessories such as Airbrush Control Valves and Airbrush Hoses.",()
10001688,brick,Airbrushing Equipment – Replacement Parts/Accessories,Definition: Includes any products that can be described/observed as a replacement part/accessory for airbrushing equipment.Includes products such as Airbrush Control Valves and Airbrush Hoses.Excludes products such as complete Airbrushes.,(20001349)
10001690,brick,Airbrushing Supplies Other,"Definition:
 Includes any products that may be described/observed as Airbrushing 
Supplies products, where the user of the schema is not able to classify 
the products in existing bricks within the schema.Excludes all currently classified Airbrushing Supplies.",()
```

As you can see column 4 and column 5 are partly quoted as they may contain line breaks, simple values are not quoted.

What I want is a 2-dimensional array where a row is level 1 and the five columns of the row are level 2.

I have tried

> fgetcsv()

which fails parsing the multiline fields and

> str_getcsv()

which fails parsing in two dimensions both with the correct parameters. How to parse this .csv-file best correctly with PHP?

Comment: [fgetcsv() can handle line breaks inside quoted strings without issue](https://3v4l.org/TV32G)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope SplFileObject::fgetcsv() helps you to parse the CSV file. In below-mentioned link the example is already given, so use that and check its get fetched properly or not.
http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php

Edit: Full code sample

```
$file = new SplFileObject('../../temp/file.csv');
$ar = array();
while (!$file->eof()) {
    array_push($ar,$file->fgetcsv());
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

Comment: Thanks for the native PHP solution.